# 4th Tab in TabLayout not responding to click event

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a TabLayout in an application. This tab layout previously had three tabs, and worked just fine. After I added a fourth tab to the layout, this tab does not respond to clicks even though there is an event wired to it in the Kotlin code.

Here is a GIF example of how the application responds:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIhaZ.jpg (it is a GIF on Imgur; it was too large to upload to SO directly)

The code controlling the TabLayout state is as follows:

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
class PlaceholderFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        println("Clicked on: ${arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)}")
        return when(arguments?.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            1 -> inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
            2 -> inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false)
            3 -> inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_assignments, container, false)
            4 -> inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scoreboard, container, false)
            // Catch all condition - if view is unimplemented, show a blank view
            else -> View(context)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private const val ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number"

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        fun newInstance(sectionNumber: Int): PlaceholderFragment {
            val fragment = PlaceholderFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber)
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

Would anybody be able to help me?

Comment: should be index 0 , 1 2,3  instead ?

Comment: I did try that - it made the second page render in the first tab. I don't know why everything isn't zero indexed, but there has to be some reason why.

Comment: How are you calling your newInstance( ) method

Comment: The newInstance() method is being called by the Fragment class as part of the implementation. It is called by the inflate method when necessary.

Comment: are you still facing the issue?